# Material not applied when importing assets through asset browser

Tags: materials, import, asset-browser

I had a model of a bed and then I changed the materials on it according to my need. Then I made it into an asset, but when I try to import it in another blend file through the asset browser, the material is not applied i.e. pink/purple material in the scene. Also this error is only happening with this asset not with other assets which I downloaded with pre-defined materials already applied to them.

[image: Original asset blend file]
(1) Original bed.blend file of the bed asset.

[image: Importing asset through asset browser]
(2) My final scene where I have imported the bed using asset browser.

Any help is much appriciated, thanks in advance.